# Не могу создать cookie на сайте, slim 3

Tags: php, cookie, slim

Нужно создать файлы cookie на сайте, я использую slim 3 и cookie создаётся в контроллере.
Я уже пробовал создавать так:

```
setcookie('test', 'test17', time() + (1 * 60), '/', '.test.org', true);
```

И так:

```
$newResponse = $response->withStatus(200)->withHeader('Set-Cookie', 'test=test17; expires=Fri, 25-Nov-2020 20:20:11 GMT; Max-Age=60; path=/; domain=.test.org; secure');
return $newResponse;
```

Всё напрасно, сайт просто не возвращает заголовок Set cookie, создание куки идёт выше любой строки вывода, оно вообще идёт в контроллере где разумеется вывода нет. Пробовал создать index.php в корне сайта и закинул туда setcookie, сработало, не знаю в чём дело. Надеюсь на помощь, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Всё оказалось просто, заголовки всё ещё невероятно чувствительная штука, вот в чём было дело:

```
return $response->withStatus(302)->withHeader("Location", $redirect);
return $response;
```

Просто забыл убрать второй return когда проверял на баги.